# How to detect if no key is currently being pressed down on the keyboard?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to make a game with arrow key movement and want to make, "when all arrow keys are not pressed then the key = nothing,". So I need a way of detecting this, I've tried to use Keyup but it doesn't work.

I tried using other questions on stack overflow but nothing I find is as related to the title as I thought it would've been. If it helps I can add some sample code below.

```
var key = "";
onkeydown = e => {
    key = e.code;
};
```

This makes it set to the code but I want it to set back to nothing when the user releases the key.

```
// ive tried this keyup method buts it so buggy
onkeyup = e => {
    key = "";
}
```

This is something but I can't use it because of all the downsides, I will add one more thing but as an example of what I'm trying to achieve, and I have no idea what I'm really doing.

```
var ifAllKeysArePressed; // I dont know what it should equal or anything
// I want the value to be boolean
setInterval(() => {
    if(!ifAllKeysArePressed) {
        key = "";
    };
}, Infinity);
```

Comment: You can't know for *sure*, a button may have been pressed prior to the window being loaded, but you'll get any updates after that.

Comment: PSA: It's time to use `let` or `const` instead of `var` when you can.

Comment: ... and [you always can](https://caniuse.com/const). The days of supporting Internet Explorer are behind us.

Comment: @isherwood There are rare cases where `var` is the right call due to scope, but these can almost always be avoided.

Comment: What is `setInterval(..., Infinity)` supposed to do?

Comment: what are you hoping / looking to do when no keys are down? how is that being used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store all currently pressed keys in a `Set`.

```js
const pressed = new Set, p = document.querySelector('p');
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  pressed.add(e.code);
  p.textContent = '';
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
  pressed.delete(e.code);
  if (!pressed.size) p.textContent = 'No keys down';
});
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Thank ou so much, this works really well!